# TensorFlow Saver unworked

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to save all variables of the model, but instead the error "*FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power*" raised. 
I havn't defined beta1_power variable. I don't know what it is.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(save_path="/home/eldmitro/MNIST",sess=tf.Session())
```

**Layers defining:**

```
def params_init(shape, name):
    w = tf.truncated_normal(shape=shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(w, name= name)

def conv2D_init(x, kernel_shape,output_channels, name, activation=tf.nn.relu):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = params_init(kernel_shape, "W")
        b = params_init([output_channels], "b")
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, filter=w, strides=[1, 1,1,1], padding='SAME', name=name))

def pool2x2(x, name):
       return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME', name=name) 

def fcl_init(x, in_neurons, out_neurons,name):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = params_init([in_neurons, out_neurons], name="W")
        b = params_init([out_neurons], name="b")
    return(tf.matmul(x, w) + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first initialize the variables then to save them. You can initialize the variables either by restoring form a checkpoint or

```
sess.run(global_variables_initializer())
```

You cannot save variables being uninitialized.

Then do this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(save_path="/home/eldmitro/MNIST",sess=sess)
```

To just store initialized(not trained) variables.